# What is the maximum distance between the top of the door and the top of the window?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Problem:**

A rectangular window is to be cut into a door 6.5 ft tall so that the window is 6 inches less than twice the distance above the window. The window must be 18 inches wide and have an area of at least 324 square inches. What is the maximum distance between the top of the door and the top of the window?

**My attempt:**

Let:

d be the distance from the top of the door to the top of the window.

x be the height of the rectangle.

6.5 ft = 78 in

Thus,

d + x + 2d - 6 = 28

3d + x - 6 = 28

3d - 6 + x = 78

3d + x = 78 + 6 = 84

84 - 3d >= 18

66 - 3d >= 0

66 >= 3d

d <= 22 in.

The book gives an answer of 10 inches.

Comment: What do you mean by "...the windows is 6 inches less ..."?

Comment: The first equation looks wrong. Plus, you have no equation corresponding to area.

Comment: You need to correct the equation from 28 to 78 in the first two lines - and it seems wrong. The height of the window is at least 18. You do not have a value for the distance of the window from the bottom (d-?). I would say that the window height x=2d-6. Assuming that the window starts from the bottom of the door, you solve it for d.